# Inscribed circle and square, find the equation for the perimeter of the nth shape in terms of n.

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

[Image is of a square with side 1 which is inscribed in a circle which is inscribed in a square and so on and so forth for ever. How do I find the equation of the nth outer shape in terms of n?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRUhE.png)

Comment: Have you attempted solving this problem or do you expect us to do all the calculations for it?

Comment: I've figured out the pattern, where you either multiply the previous perimeter with sqrt(2)pi/4 or multiply it by 4 depending on whether n is even or odd. But I cannot find a single equation to show this where the value changes depending on if n is even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

The radius of the first circle is easily found with Pythagore (half of the square's diagonal). This radius is also the half of the length of the second square, thus. You find the radius of the second circle with Pythagore again, and so on: $$c_1 = 1$$ $$r_1 = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{c_1^2 + c_1^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}c_1$$
$$c_2 = 2.r_1 = 2.\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}c_1=\sqrt{2}c_1$$
$$r_2 = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{c_2^2 + c_2^2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}c_2 = \frac{2}{2}c_1 = c_1$$
$$c_3 = \ ...$$

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to come up with a single equation that describes the perimeter in terms of "n"?

Comment: I guess you can find it by recurrence: you see that $r_2 = r_1.\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}$ for instance, try to continue the calculations for further $c$ and $r$ and you should find a formula

Comment: (It is possible that $r_n = (2/\sqrt{2})^{n-1}r_1 = (2/\sqrt{2})^{n-2}c_1$, but verify)